# Java 8 predicate validator implementation

Tags: java, validation

I read this (article|https://dzone.com/articles/fail-fast-validations-using) about Java validator implementation.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class GenericValidator<T> implements Predicate {

  private final List<Predicate<T>> validators = new LinkedList<>();

  public GenericValidator(List<Predicate<T>> validators) {
    this.validators.addAll(validators);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean test(final T toValidate) {
    return validators.parallelStream()
                 .allMatch(predicate -> predicate.test(toValidate));
  }
}
```

Isn't this call to test a recursive call? say, predicate.test is called inside test function implements Predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a recursive call as inside GenericValidator#test you are calling predicate.test(tovalidate), where the predicate is the object you have passed through constructor during object creation of GenericValidator. So,

```
predicate -> predicate.test(toValidate)
```

the above statement will call the test method of predicates (you have passed a list of the predicate) you have passed as a constructor argument. Below is the code by which you can test it easily.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Practice {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
     List<Predicate<Integer>> vaList = new ArrayList<>();
     vaList.add(Practice::isGreaterThan5);
     vaList.add(Practice::isLessThan10);
     GenericValidator<Integer> genericValidator = new GenericValidator(vaList);
     genericValidator.test(8);
    }

    public static boolean isGreaterThan5(int e){
        System.out.println("Is greater than 5");
        return e>5;
    }

    public static boolean isLessThan10(int e){
        System.out.println("Is less than 10");
        return e<10;
    }

}


 class GenericValidator<T> implements Predicate<T> {

  private final List<Predicate<T>> validators = new LinkedList<>();

  public GenericValidator(List<Predicate<T>> validators) {
    this.validators.addAll(validators);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean test(final T toValidate) {
      System.out.println("Validating the input inside test....");
    return validators.parallelStream()
                 .allMatch(predicate -> predicate.test(toValidate));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Validating the input inside test....
Is greater than 5
Is less than 10
```

So you can see that it "Validating the input inside test" has a print only once. Hence it will not a recursive call.

**EDIT:**

Here I am trying answer you queries in comment. Below is the example of the old way by implementing Predicate interfaces. However, It is highly discouraged to do so.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Practice {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Predicate<Integer>> vaList = new ArrayList<>();
        vaList.add(new GeraterThan5Predicate());
        vaList.add(new LessThan10Predicate());
        GenericValidator<Integer> genericValidator = new GenericValidator(vaList);
        genericValidator.test(8);
    }
}

class GeraterThan5Predicate implements Predicate<Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer e) {
        System.out.println("Is greater than 5");
        return e > 5;
    }

}

class LessThan10Predicate implements Predicate<Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer e) {
        System.out.println("Is less than 10");
        return e > 10;
    }

}

class GenericValidator<T> implements Predicate<T> {

    private final List<Predicate<T>> validators = new LinkedList<>();

    public GenericValidator(List<Predicate<T>> validators) {
        this.validators.addAll(validators);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(final T toValidate) {
        System.out.println("Validating the input inside test....");
        return validators.parallelStream().allMatch(predicate -> predicate.test(toValidate));
    }
}
```

And for your why you need to implement Predicate interface by GenericValidator. I can't really answer that. If you write your GenericValidator class like below still it works.

```
class GenericValidator<T>{

    private final List<Predicate<T>> validators = new LinkedList<>();

    public GenericValidator(List<Predicate<T>> validators) {
        this.validators.addAll(validators);
    }

    public boolean test(final T toValidate) {
        System.out.println("Validating the input inside test....");
        return validators.parallelStream().allMatch(predicate -> predicate.test(toValidate));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does GenericValidator<T> need to implement Predicate<T> then? You are not using Predicate<T> in your main

Comment: Do you know what is method reference, lamdas, and functional interfaces and how those work? If not I will add an example of the old way by implementing predicate interface. Also, I will suggest to go through those topics.